# Jinja2Exception Flask template not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am getting the error jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound. Even I have my HTML files in the templates folder, still I am receiving this error. It was working fine sometime ago, and now I am getting this error.

Full error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "E:\price\web\flasktest.py", line 6, in index
return render_template('about.html')
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1068, in get_or_select_template
return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 997, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, globals)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 125, in load
source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 60, in get_source
return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
File "E:\price\web\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: about.html
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask('test', template_folder= 'templates')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, host = '127.0.0.1', port = 5000)
```

Here is the screenshot of my directories:

[image]

Update:

1. My code is working perfectly in a new file. Is it due to cache?
2. Tried app = Flask(**name**) but still same issue.

[image]

3. A new Test.py file works completely fine but not the old ones.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `render_template('templates/about.html')`?

Comment: Tried but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this topic https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#application-object and head over this section **About the First Parameter**

so my guess, you should import the right package name,

so try `__name__` instead of `test`

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
```

BTW, `Flask` already expects `templates` as default folder to look at, meaning it's optional and you can define your app like so

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I have tried that, and I updated the code's screenshot above. You can check it once, it isn't working.

Comment: Thank you I didn't noticed that I was doing '__name__' instead of __name__.

Answer (score 0):

Flask looks for templates by default in the "templates" folder https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates.

Try this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
  @app.route('/')
  def index():
    return render_template('about.html')
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But I have tried that and it didn't worked so I had to give the location. But when I tried the same code in a py new file, Flask is working but not in the old file.

Comment: Did you set up the FLASK_APP environment variable to point to the right file?

Comment: Yes like set FLASK_APP = flasktest.py correct?
It shows me 500 Internal Server error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution where it went wrong.

I was doing this:

```
app = Flask('__name__')
```

But the correct way was this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```